# Android app doesn't show up on Google Play in a phone search but it does in a web search

Tags: android

I posted my app about the month ago, I could see it in the web search on Google PLay the very  next day, but if I try to search with any android device I can't find it.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Are you really, really sure that your device is supported?

Comment: Could you show your manifest ?

Comment: @SteveHarrig You app isn't compatible with my Nexus 7 and my Samsung GT-I9001. Please show your manifest.

Comment: Your app is incompatible with Samsung S3 for some reason. Can you post your manifest?

Comment: the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822676/android-app-compatible-with-0-devices

Answer (score 0):

Have you only checked from your phone? What is the name of the app and I will try to search it

Comment: It shows up as incompatible to all devices. Lists it as android 2.2 and up. Can you post your manifest?