# Android app compatible with 0 devices

Tags: android, compatibility

My app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picturesexperience.camera is not visible on any mobile device. Installs with no problem from the APK file (that is actually how I distribute my app right now), works perfectly, but for some reason Google Play doesn't list it. Any suggestions.

The app uses QR code scanning library from Zxing, everything else is custom coded.

The app's manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.picturesexperience.camera"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.picturesexperience.camera.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".UploadActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".PictureViewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
```

...should be...

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

The `uses-feature` is [case sensitive](http://samwize.com/2013/05/09/android-use-feature-element-is-case-sensitive/) and [lower case](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features), so in effect you're stating that you're using a feature that does not exist on any device.

Comment: It worked perfectly too! Mine was written `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />`

Answer (score 3):

#### Case sensitive

Permissions and features are case sensitive. Try with the following instead:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

#### Required=false

Also make sure to add `android:required="false"`for max device compatibility. Otherwise devices without back camera (like nexus 7 tablet) will still be ruled out.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Answer (score 1):

I have face this problem, but after searing a few hours i got a solution in my app.
I am using

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

while its should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

So that i want to say that please check carefully your permissions and feathers. Also remove those permission which is not required in your application this thing will increase support device.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer, I face the same problem. With setting all users-features as `false`, **play store still shows zero devices supported**.

Here is solution, hope will help someone

```
 <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
```

Also

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check why your app is incompatible by checking the device catalog:

- Select device catalog from menu

[image: menu entry 'device catalog']

- Show all devices

[image: devices filter]

- Then select any device, click on the blue arrow to see details and check the entry 'track status'

[image]