# Android app is supported by 0 devices in android

Tags: android

I am getting Android app is supported by 0 devices. Dose any body konw What is this issue

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: @mujjuraja Question is very much Clear.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

still getting same error

Comment: Remove the READ_LOGS permission

Comment: Which IDE are you using? VS, Android Studio? Did you manually add these permissions or did the IDE add them for you?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 6):

The `uses-feature` is case sensitive and lower case, so in effect you're stating that you're using a feature that does not exist on any device.

That should be like this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

**Edit**: I would try removing all permissions and add these permission one by one to test it.

Comment: remove also the android :required false from <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

Comment: used  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/> instead you using

Answer (score 0):

your question seems like that

[Android app compatible with 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822676/android-app-compatible-with-0-devices)

The autofocus could be your problem since it should be in lower case